# How to create bottom tab navigation using react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am going to implement a react native footer menu (bottom tam navigator). But I got some errors on running it.

this is my drawer.js file

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {View,Text,StyleSheet} from "react-native";
import {createAppContainer}from "react-navigation";
import {createMaterialBootomTabNavigator} from "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs";
import Homescreen from "./home.js";

class drawer extends React.Component{


    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>drawer</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}


const styles=StyleSheet.create({

    container:{
        flex:1,
        justifyContent:"center",
        alignItems:"center",
    }
});

const TabNavigator=createMaterialBootomTabNavigator(
    {
    Home:{
        screen:Homescreen,
    }

    },

    {
        initialRouteName:"home",
        activeColor:"#f0edf6",
        inactiveColor:"#3e2465",
        barStyle:{ backgroundColor: '#694fad' },
        
    }


);

export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

I had already installed the react-navigator.

By run it on my emulator I got this error.
[image]

how can I fix this?

Comment: You are using the wrong spelling here, it should be `bottom` not `bootom` `createMaterialBootomTabNavigator`

Answer (score 0):

Change createMaterialBootomTabNavigator to createMaterialBottomTabNavigator